# SQL Server 2012 - Sumar cada dia, las ventas de los ultimos 7 dias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito en SQL Server 2012 agrupar y sumar las ventas de cada dia.

```
|Fecha     |Monto|
|01/01/2020|  5  |
|01/01/2020|  5  |
|02/01/2020| 10  |
|02/01/2020| 10  |
|03/01/2020| 15  |
|03/01/2020| 15  |
.
.
.
```

Posteriormente o al mismo tiempo en otra columna y en cada fila, obtener la suma
de los ultimos 7 dias como muestro en el ejemplo. Las primeras 6 filas se descartan porque no hay ventas antes del primero de enero de 2020.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usé esto, pero me da las ventas semanales y quiero en cada fila la suma de los 7 anteriores.

```
select 
    ((DATEDIFF(day, @to_date, [Date]))/7) Semana
    ,DATEADD(DD, ((DATEDIFF(day, @to_date, [Date]))/7)*7,@to_date) Fecha
    ,SUM(Venta)
group by 
    ((DATEDIFF(day, @to_date, [Date]))/7)
    ,DATEADD(DD, ((DATEDIFF(day, @to_date, [Date]))/7)*7,@to_date)
```

Comment: Puedes subir lo que has intentando, por favor. Bienvenido a stack overflow, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que formules mejor tus preguntas.

Comment: Y además que especifiques que base de datos es la que estas usando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función de ventana `sum()` donde, para indicar que quieres sumar un número determinado de filas, puedes valerte de la cláusula `rows` dentro del `over`, indicando que quieres sumar las últimas 7 filas, así:

```
select   Fecha
       , Monto
       , sum(Monto) over (order by fecha rows between 6 preceding and current row) Monto7Dias
  from VentaDiaria
```

Esto suma las 6 filas anteriores y la fila actual, dando un total de 7 filas en la suma.